# How to set default paragraph style to "normal" in email replies in Evolution?

Tags: configuration, email, evolution, style

When I answer an email in Evolution 3.2.3 (Ubuntu 12.04) the new text I write has the paragraph style "normal" and is wrapped, but the quoted text of the email I answer to has the paragraph style "**preformatted**" and is not wrapped. As my screen is only 15 inch although wide, I normally don't see to whole text. I need to change the paragraph style manually for the quoted email part to "normal" so the next is wrapped and readable without the need to scroll to to side every line. It does not matter whether I change the email to html (from text) or change the reply style.
Is there a way to set the the default paragraph style for the whole answer email to "**normal**"?

I thought it was different in previous version of Evolution (this "new behaviour" happens at least since Ubuntu 10.10, Evolution 2.30.3), but I don't know exactly when the change happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only [answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12442588&postcount=5) found so far, thanks to [David](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=7532):
Evolution retains the formatting of the original message, some other clients auto-wrap and others don't and you have to deal with what you receive from them.

I don't think there has ever been a way to automatically change this but you might be able to "hack" one of the default Evolution config files (somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in Evolution, just like it's not possible to choose font style. This is unique and loudly advertised feature of Evolution to further streamline and converge email workflow - Evolution knows what is the best for you.
Please use different email client if you are not satisfied with Evolution's choice.